# Bottom div with horizontally sliding content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need an div that will be always at the bottom of the page, margin 172px at the left, and 383px at the right.

This div will have some images and text and left and right buttons. When you hover the mouse at the right button, for example, the content that was "invisible", after reaching the div's width limit, will start appearing from the right, sliding the content for the left.

I tried using `position:fixed; bottom:0px`, but I couldn't margin the div, and the width of it doesn't change when the screen size changes...

For example, this would be exactly what I want (the black div at the bottom):

[image]

If you know any jquery plugin that does what I want or if you know how to do something like this, please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `position: fixed`, margin can not be applied. You can specify the `left` and `right` attributes though.

```
position: fixed;
right: 383px;
bottom: 0;
left: 172px;
```

I know it's not exactly what you're asking for, but you can then set the `white-space` and `overflow` attributes on that div to make it so that it will show a horizontal scrollbar.

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: auto;
```

The user would use the scrollbar on the bottom to move the content of the div. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rustyjeans/5nv84/

To use jQuery set `overflow: hidden` and add some functions that adjust the `scrollLeft` of the div, then add some controls that call those functions when they're hovered. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rustyjeans/FtSGn/

Comment: Ok, fixing the div worked. But the div's content keeps "line breaking" when it reaches the div limit. How do I fix it?

Comment: `white-space: nowrap` should be stopping the content from breaking; unless it contains `<br>` or block elements like divs. If you have block elements you'll need to set `display: inline-block` on those elements to make them display next to each other.

Comment: Oh I would like to use jquery to move the content of the div, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be too hard to do.  You want a containing div that has the dimensions of the viewer.  Then, have a div inside that one, with position absolute and dimensions that extend beyond the viewer in width. When the arrows are hovered over use jquery to change the "left" css property of the inner div. Did that help?

EDIT:
The outer div should have "position: relative;" to insure that the inner div is positioned relative to its margins.